# how to temporarily change ruby version for Rails 4 project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I've created Rails 4 project with Ruby 2.0.
How can I temporarily change Ruby's version to 1.9.3.

I tried to add a line in Gemfile:

```
ruby "1.9.3"
```

But when I run rake task, it's showing:

```
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/definition.rb:361:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.0.0, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler.rb:116:in `setup'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:73:in `setup'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195@global/gems/rubygems-bundler-1.2.0/lib/rubygems-bundler/noexec.rb:85:in `<top (required)>'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `require'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:110:in `rescue in require'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p195/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:35:in `require'
    from /home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p195/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:9:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use `rvm`. Type in your console:

```
rvm install 1.9.3 # if you don't have appropriate version installed
rvm use 1.9.3
```

Then you should run

```
bundle
```

to install your gems (it's because local gems after switching to `1.9.3` will be empty) and it should work.

Comment: And, oscar will also have to run Bundler, to get all gems for Ruby 1.9.3.

Comment: he would need to install bundler first `gem install bundler`

Answer (score 2):

create .rvmrc file for your project

while at the root of your application run the command

```
rvm use 1.9.3@rails3 --create --rvmrc
```

so whenever you step into the project directory ruby version will change to 1.9.3 and will use gemset 'rails3'.